# Block user not listed in vhost

Tags: php, apache, webserver, vhosts

I am using vhosts file in my Apache server and I have hundreds of domains pointing each one to one DocumentRoot folder.

The problem is that when a user comes to my server from a domain that is not listed in my vhosts apache will treat the FIRST entry in my vhosts as default. I would not like that. I would like to block the user, not display any page.

How can I do that?

Comment: how do they *arrive* at the server is the domain is not hosted there? the dns should not be pointing unhosted domains to your server

Comment: they create and A record and point it to my server IP.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is what you want:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
DocumentRoot /www/default
//or what ever

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. But the user will not be redirect, he/she will see a NOT FOUND page consuming my server resources. I would like to block any response to that user. Like using "Deny all" when the user comes from a domain not listed. Is it possible?

Comment: if a domain resolves to your ip, and some one 'hits' that ip some resources will always be consumed. "Deny all" also uses resources. the only way to not use any resources is to change the dns entry.